# How to copy files & directories as a Sudo User

Tags: sudo

I login to linux using my Id eg "A". then i'll sudo to the user 'B' without entering the password, after that i'll copy some files from X folder to Y Folder using the SUdo user 'B'.

I am trying to do this activity with a shell script to put it in the cronjob... so far no luck.

Any help on this will be really appreicate...

this is what i am trying...

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo /usr/local/sbin/deploy
cp -r /tmp/test /tmp/deploy
```

Comment: So what problems are you getting? Does user B have write access to the directory `/tmp/deploy`?

Comment: Wrong site. This should be on http://superuser.com/ .

Comment: Copy works fine... it copies as the User "A" not "B".

[pota713@lnx33 /tmp]$ ./cp1.sh
 --- Switching users ---
User Name     :  deploy
UID           :  498
Home Dir      :  /opt/mover
Erase set to backspace.
<lnx33:~>$ exit
[pota713@lnx33 /tmp]$ cd deploy
[pota713@lnx33 deploy]$ ls
test
[pota713@lnx33 deploy]$ ls -ltr
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  3 pota713 acn 4096 Nov 16 07:59 test

Regards,
Ramesh.T

Answer (score 1):

You must run the `cp` with `sudo` as well. Otherwise, `deploy` creates the files with owner `B` and then, the `cp` can't read them (since the shell returns you to the original user when the `sudo` in your script completes).

Alternatively, run `chmod` with `sudo` to make the files readable for `A` and then make a copy.

Answer (score 0):

sudo only runs the command on the commandline, then returns you back to the invoker's account. if you want to run multiple commands as another user, it would be better to create a script and run that script via sudo.

Answer (score 0):

**sudo** is an interactive command. Using it in cron jobs does not make sense. Either you create a super user script to copy all the files and then change the ownership, or run the script by the required user itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: for example if your username is "james", add the following entry to the `/etc/sudoers` or into a separate `/etc/sudoers.d/` file. After this, you can copy files from source to target without entering password.

```
# visudo 
james  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/cp
```